# Получение данных с html <input> в TypeScript

Tags: html, typescript

Не могу получить значения с html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">      
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="helloworld.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
        <input id="myValue" type="number"></input>
        <input id="myUnit" type="text"></input>
        <button onclick="foo()">button</button>
</body>
</html>
```

TypeScript код

```
namespace asd{
    function foo(){
        var value = parseFloat((<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("myValue")).value);
        var unit = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("myUnit")).value; 
        let myObject: MyObject = new MyObject(value, unit);
        console.log("getvalues success");
    }
    class MyObject {
        value: number;
        unit: string; 
        constructor(value: number, unit: string){
             this.value = value;
             this.unit = unit;
        }
    }
    class Startup {
        public static main(): void{
            console.log("script work!");
       }
    }
    Startup.main(); 
}
```

Ошибка в консоли браузера firefox

ReferenceError: foo is not defined index.html:1:1

Помогите пожалуйста, заранее спасибо

Comment: Вы функцию определяете за классами. Надо внутри одного из них (Startup)

Answer (score 0):

кому любопытно но нет компилятора: http://typescriptlang.org/play

ошибка в отсутствии `export` вызывать так `asd.foo()`

```
namespace asd{
export function foo(){ //< --- export--вызов asd.foo()
    console.log("button click");
    var value = parseFloat((<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("myValue")).value);
    var unit = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("myUnit")).value; 
    let myObject: MyObject = new MyObject(value, unit);
}
class MyObject {
    value: number;
    unit: string; 
    constructor(value: number, unit: string){
         this.value = value;
         this.unit = unit;
         console.log('getvalues',value,unit);
    }
}
class Startup {
    public static main(): void{
        console.log("script work!");
   }
}
Startup.main(); 
}
```

---

```
<button onclick="asd.foo()">button</button>
```

---

```js
var asd;
(function(asd) {
  function foo() {
    console.log("button click");
    var value = parseFloat(document.getElementById("myValue").value);
    var unit = document.getElementById("myUnit").value;
    var myObject = new MyObject(value, unit);
  }
  asd.foo = foo;
  var MyObject = /** @class */ (function() {
    function MyObject(value, unit) {
      this.value = value;
      this.unit = unit;
      console.log('getvalues', '' + unit + '' + value);
    }
    return MyObject;
  }());
  var Startup = /** @class */ (function() {
    function Startup() {}
    Startup.main = function() {
      console.log("script work!");
    };
    return Startup;
  }());
  Startup.main();
})(asd || (asd = {}));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="helloworld.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <input id="myValue" type="number" value="2"></input>
  <input id="myUnit" type="text" value="U"></input>
  <button onclick="asd.foo()">button</button>
</body>

</html>
```